# Issue with .HTACCESS rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect [domain.com/engine.php?v=917XOk1u1B0](http://domain.com/engine.php?v=917XOk1u1B0) to [domain.com/watch?v=917XOk1u1B0](http://domain.com/watch?v=917XOk1u1B0) via htaccess my current working htaccess code is here.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)?$ engine.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Comment: How can I add ?v= after /watch like watch?v=917XOk1u1B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.+)$

RewriteRule ^watch/?$ /engine.php [QSA,L]
```

This will  redirect

```
domain.com/watch?v=12345
```

to

```
 domain.com/engine.php?v=12345
```

Comment: got 404 Not Found The requested URL /watch was not found on this server.

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: redirects what I need but not found. testing here https://ytvideodownloader.xyz/engine.php?v=hTWKbfoikeg

Comment: resolved issue with cloudflare page rule. not sure its good approach or not. current .htaccess RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^watch$ engine.php [L] cloudflare page rule https://ytvideodownloader.xyz/engine.php*Forwarding to https://ytvideodownloader.xyz/watch$1

Comment: @SalmanZaib I was confused, in your question you said that "redirect from /engine.php to /watch, My answer was correct, But you actually wanted to redirect /watch to /engine.php, I have edited the answer accordingly. you can accept my answer if you are happy with it.